# ESLint with typescript "Parsing error: Type expected" with Template Literal Types

Tags: typescript, eslint, template-strings

I have this type:

```
export type ICfnOutput = {
    ENDPOINTS: {
        [key in `${keyof typeof MSERVICES}_ENDPOINT`]: string
    },
    USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID: string,
    amplifyClientUrl: string,
    USER_POOL_ID: string
}
```

When I run the command:

```
eslint .  --ext .ts
```

I get the following error:

```
error  Parsing error: Type expected
```

`.eslintrc.json`

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {}
}
```

Im using eslint `v8.21.0`, how can I avoid this, or should I ignore it and add an ignore command because seems to be an eslint problem

The code is working fine is just when I lint eslint takes it as an error.

Comment: Sounds like an outdated parser that doesn't understand template literal types.

Comment: @caTS Sure, but [ESLint 8.21.0 came out in Aug 2022](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/eslint-v8.21.0-released/), and TypeScript template literal support has been around since 2020 per [typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#2583](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2583). @Woohaik Do you have an ESLint config file with a configuration that [specifies `@typescript-eslint`](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/#step-2-configuration)? Can you post it here?

Comment: @JeffBowman I edited and added the .eslintrc.json

Comment: This doesn't even compile for me when I paste it in the TypeScript playground, _without_ ESLint.

Comment: @Bbrk24 you are probably missing the "MSERVICES" object

Comment: Stubbing in `MSERVICES`, this seems to work with or without your config [in the typescript-eslint playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.8.4&sourceType=module&code=MYewdgzgLgBAsgZQKICUBqBJAwkhMC8MA3gLABQMMAYgPI0BcMARAEICCKT5AvueQKYAPAA4gATrCgBPYfxjYAZmBoBXKMLUFi5SkgByAEQAKNDHoAqCRqQqUYAbQDW-KTACWYGAAMAJEWdSIAow0rJB8Mjo2LjcAPr6xqYWXgC6jNBiHgDmOjDcADS5AKqRsSY0ADKxWBUY+uaxGAbpUJlgWYW2AIYAtsIANm4KUliD-GBQRWL9LW0dxaXlVU2z2TzkQA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA). Are you calling the right `eslint`? Do you need `npx eslint`?

Comment: @JeffBowman thank you for the playground, I see and double checked and the problem was the typescript version, Im using the aws cdk and apparently by default install typescript v3.9.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved in the comments:

> I see and double checked and the problem was the typescript version, Im using the aws cdk and apparently by default install typescript v3.9.7. —[Woohaik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17200950/woohaik)

Template literal types were [introduced in TypeScript 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html), so ESLint was correctly flagging that this syntax was unexpected.

It was helpful to debug this through the use of the [Typescript-ESLint Playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.8.4&sourceType=module&code=MYewdgzgLgBAsgZQKICUBqBJAwkhMC8MA3gLABQMMAYgPI0BcMARAEICCKT5AvueQKYAPAA4gATrCgBPYfxjYAZmBoBXKMLUFi5SkgByAEQAKNDHoAqCRqQqUYAbQDW-KTACWYGAAMAJEWdSIAow0rJB8Mjo2LjcAPr6xqYWXgC6jNBiHgDmOjDcADS5AKqRsSY0ADKxWBUY+uaxGAbpUJlgWYW2AIYAtsIANm4KUliD-GBQRWL9LW0dxaXlVU2z2TzkQA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA).